# I can't get Laravel Auth::attempt working,

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I've read a lot of question about it, but i couldn't got right question for my case.

So i'm learning Laravel 8 right now, i want to authenticate user manually, so i want to use Auth::attempt, but it always return false/error, i don't which part oh my code that wrong, hopefully i will got my answer. Here is my code

routes/web.php

```
Route::post('/login',[LoginController::class,'authenticate']);
```

login.blade.php

```
<form action="/login" method="POST">
     @csrf
     <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-login">LOGIN</button>
     </div>                                   
</form>
```

LoginController.php

```
public function authenticate(Request $request){

        //mengecek apakah user ada di database
        if(Auth::attempt(['username'=>$request->username,'password'=>$request->password])){
            echo "Login Suskes";
        }else{
            echo "Login Error";
        }
    }
```

model/User.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $table = 'user';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = [
        'username',
        'password',
        'nama',
        'id_level_user',
        'id_sub_unit'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

I don't know which part is wrong, so i will very thankful if someone help me answer it, it's for my diploma Final Project

Thanks

Comment: By default, Laravel uses the email field for authentication. If you would like to customize this, you may define a username method on your LoginController: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication

Comment: @KamleshPaul i've change it on attempt method with username and password

Comment: you need to register before login have you register ? user

Answer (score 1):

In your LoginController add the following function:

```
public function username()
{
    return 'username'; //or whatever field
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How did you seed your users table?

Maybe you did not encrypt your password correctly.
And the check is always returning false because of the incorrect password.

Try to reset your password.
There should be a link in your form (if you are using the default auth UI).
Or you can go to `password/reset` in your browser to reset your password.

Set you MAIL_DRIVER=log

And check your log for the link in the email, that link will send you to a form to reset your password.

Comment: i'm using existing database, so i don't seed users table, will it work?

Comment: If you don't have users, how could it work?You need to create an user. You can go to `/register` to create your user.

Comment: i have users table, with existing data, i mean i didn't seed users table from laravel, i'm using existing users data, i don't use laravel auth ui

Comment: Did you hashed the password? Which function did you used to hash it?